# Vue multiselect show always behind Bootstrap input groups

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2

I'm having a really hard time with this.
I'm using [Vue Multiselect](http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/) and Bootstrap's 3 Input Groups.

The problem here is that the multiselect options show behind the input group no matter what z-index I use on it. I know that I can change input group z-index to 0, but watching Bootstrap SASS files it says: "Ensure that the input is always above the *appended* addon button for proper border colors" so I don't know if it is safe to do this:

```
.input-group .form-control {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

I tried every selector on the multiselect but none makes effect. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cristiancastrodc/c9gdxg3s/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the cause of this is that in the `vue-multiselect.min.css` file that defines these stylings, `.multiselect--active` only has a z-index of 1. Clicking the multiselect dropdown toggles that active class.

Changing the z-index on `.multiselect--active` to something greater than 2, which is the value for the input box, would probably be the best way to solve this issue.

I've put this updated solution in a new [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/n2jjkejp/)

Comment: No way!! I've tried everything but this! You saved me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.input-group {
  z-index: -1;
}
```